# How to convert SQL to Mongoose query api

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am interested if the below mention select can be written in a mongoose query API style, for example:

```
SessionModel.findOne().where({ token: token}).and() ...
```

or

```
SessionModel.findOne().where('token').equals(token).and().where('status').nin(['blocked', 'deleted'])
```

Select Statement:

```
SELECT * FROM session WHERE token = :token and (status != 'deleted' OR status != 'blocked');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- token match you already did,
- status match `$nin` not in from array `["deleted", "blocked"]`

```
SessionModel.findOne()
  .where('token').equals(token)
  .where('status').nin(["deleted", "blocked"]);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/As6k9XnO8_A)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i would like it in this style: SessionModel.findOne().where('refreshToken').equals(refreshToken).and().where('status').nin(['blocked', 'deleted']) . Is it right? I think this is more readable )